# Where can I find definition of all built-in variables in Metal shading language?

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

I get a snippet of Metal shader, but I can't find information of the built-in variables like `_surface` and so on.

```
float AO = _surface.ambientOcclusion;
float lightContrib = _lightingContribution.diffuse.r;
lightContrib *= AO;


// mask of fresnel
float mask = _surface.specular.b;
float fresnel = saturate(dot(_surface.view, _surface.normal));
```

Where can I find definition of all built-in variables in Metal shader language? I even can't find that in Apple specification [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not exposed by Metal, but are specific to the SceneKit framework.

They are part of the [`SCNShadable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) feature and you can find some information in the documentation for the different entry points:

1. [`SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypointgeometry)
2. [`SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypointsurface)
3. [`SCNShaderModifierEntryPointLightingModel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypointlightingmodel)
4. [`SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypointfragment)

The `<SceneKit/SCNShadable.h>` header file also contains documentation and examples.

Comment: Exactly what I want! Than you